# Web service issue in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services

I have a web service used by my iPhone application.The application accesses the webservice to get authenticated.

My question is how to **intimate the user** when the server doesn't sends any response when it is called.

ie..The control doesn't comes to

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response
{
}
```

Comment: Which authentication method is used by the webservice ? (Basic, Digest, Kerberos,... ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start the login, also start an `NSTimer` to call a "no response" handler.  Something like this:

```
timeout = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10.0];
timeoutTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:timeout interval:0 target:self selector:@selector(failLogin) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timeoutTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[loginUrlConnection start];
```

Now you need a `failLogin` method to kill the `loginUrlConnection`.  Be sure to invalidate the timer when a response does come in:

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response {
   [timeoutTimer invalidate];
   /* Handle response... */
}
```